# Conditionally apply classes depending on route location in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, haml

My goal is to add a class to body depending on the route that AngularJS is serving on.

For example, I'd like to do this (in HAML):

```
%body#body{:class => "{{$route.current.templateUrl}}"}
```

`$route` refers to the var found in the documentation here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route)

This is so that if I visit `/#/whatever`, it should load up a `whatever.html` template and that template filename should show up as a class so that it's `<body class="whatever.html">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are resolved in context of `scope`. So the binding property has to be made available on the scope.
What you could do is inject `$route` into you controller and assign it's property that you want to bind to the controllers `$scope` property, like

```
$scope.templateUrl=$route.current.templateUrl;
```

Then bind to `templateUrl`